# What happens if you run out of fuel AND resources while flying?

Tags: mass-effect-2

In Mass Effect 2 you have a fuel resource that is used for travel within a certain map-type (between a star system and the full-map view.)  If you run out of this fuel, you start burning through your resources (minerals and element zero.)  However, I have no idea what happens if you run out of those as well.  Do you just get stranded, lose the game, get a funny comment, turn into a pie?

What happens if you run out of fuel AND resources and then try to continue flying?

Comment: I believe you are transported to the nearest mass relay station with some funny dialog.

Comment: Added to my list of Interesting things that are too scary to try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a video where it says that if you run out of fuel AND resources, you get teleported to the nearest fuel depot.

EDIT thanks to BlackVegetable:  Your credits have not been depleted, so it is possible to buy more fuel (given that you have enough credits to do so).

[Video of 5 things you shouldn't do in ME2.](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/videos/view/the-escapist-presents/1442-Five-Things-You-Shouldnt-Do-in-Mass-Effect-2)

Comment: Uh, why wouldn't you have the possibility of buying more?  Your credits aren't drained for fuel.